# page--user--login.tpl.php is not recognized

Tags: theming, users

drupal isn't recognising the page--user--login.tpl.php file.  Tried clearing the cache. Still not working. I've never themed the user login page before. Any idea's?

I am running Drupal 7 and I want to theme the whole page.
The other page template is being picked up.
There isn't any other page--user--login.tpl.php in my theme directory

the page--user.tpl.php is being recognised but the page--user-login-tpl.php is not.
bummer because i want the login page to be considerably different to the user page.

Comment: what version of drupal are you running?

Comment: What do wou want to change? The whole page or only the form?

Comment: I am running D7, and i want to theme the whole page.

Comment: it's the correct template name then, are other page templates in the same directory being picked up?  if there is another page--user--login.tpl.php file elsewhere in your theme's directory structure, that one might be being picked up instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712061/style-drupal-7-log-in-page ?

Comment: The other page template is being picked up yes, there isn't any other page--user--login.tpl.php in my theme directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712061/style-drupal-7-log-in-page

It looks like you need to also have:

- a page.tpl.php in your theme for page--anything-else.tpl.php to work
- a page--user.tpl.php in your theme

You should also always clear the theme cache after adding/removing template files.

Comment: looked promising! gave it a go. couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If it works the same way as node.tpl.php, you'll need page.tpl.php in your theme for page--anything-else.tpl.php to work (big if though, I haven't tried it)

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: ah ok. maybe i havent got it to work. the page--user.tpl.php file is being recognised however the page--user--login.tpl.php is still not being recognised.

Comment: More about having page--user.tpl.php requirement to alter page--user--login.tpl.php --- It's not the exact case. 
Say, if you want to have a custom comment.tpl.php variation (comment--blog.tpl.php), then you do need the base template in the theme's template folder to work (at least I had to).

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

```
 function themename_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
$hooks['user-login'] = array(
    'template' => 'templates/user-login',
    'render element' => 'form',
 );
  return $hooks;
}
```

Add this code to your template.php file. Then you can create user-login.tpl.php.

Note: Don't forget to clear the cache